Can a dryer vent duct be in contact with PVC pipe?
I was not happy with the ducting setup, which had an excessive amount of foil ducting with deteriorating duct tape as a sealer with loose connections. So I'm aiming for an all-rigid solution with proper appliance tape and a magvent mv-90, but am a total novice at all of this.
There is a sewage or drain pipe that runs right above where the ducting needs to go. There is very little clearance available between the floor and the pipe. If the ducting comes in contact with the pipe, and/or rests on the floor (laminate I think), is there a worry about a possible fire hazard that I should be concerned with? FWIW, it was like this for 20 years basically.


Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. I've revised your post to ask just one question, as is our policy. Your previous information can be found in the edit history in case you need it for a new question.

Heat should not be a problem. If the dryer exhaust is hotter than 200F something is badly wrong with it.
To avoid piercing pipes use short screws and don't screw into metal.
You could possibly benefit by having more corner parts where it goes into the wall.
